# In google sheets, want to copy cell values from 1 sheet to another if a specific cell has any text

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have this working well:

=if('Lee''s sheet'!$AP2="x",'Lee''s sheet'!B2,"")

which will populate cell values into a cell, from 1 sheet to another if there is an "X" marked in column AP.

I want to run the same formula but if ANY text or number is AP column (as opposed to just an X)

Answer (score 0):

Test for the length of the cell contents; it is is greater than zero, then B2, else ""

The specific sheet reference is untested, but taken from your example.

`=if(len('Lee''s sheet'!$AP2)>0,'Lee''s sheet'!B2,"")`